# Do we really need to bind Oracle service in PCF , can't we just use credentials mentioned in service?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a question what is the difference if I just use a Oracle/MySQL service provided by PCF without binding it? What difference will it create. I can anyway access DB using the credentials

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences that come to mind:

1. When you create a service through the Cloud Foundry marketplace, that will create backing resources for the service but in most cases it does *not* create credentials. The act of binding a service to your app, in most cases with most service brokers, will actually create service credentials for you. When you unbind, again with most brokers, the service credentials are destroyed. This makes it easy to regenerate your service credentials, just unbind/rebind the service and restart your app. The net result is that if you don't bind, there are no credentials.
2. Most people do not want to include credentials with the actual application (see https://12factor.net/ for details why). They want to be able to provide configuration external to the app. On Cloud Foundry this commonly amounts to binding a service.

Having said that, how do you want to provide the credentials to your application?

Service bindings are there to try and make life as a developer easier but you don't have to use them. If you want to pass in the configuration some other way, like via environment variables, a config file, or using a config service (Spring Cloud Config Server or Vault) those are fine options too.

If you do not want to bind a service to your app, the only thing you'll need to do is to create a service key instead. A service key is like a binding, but not associated with an application. It will also generate a set of unique credentials. You can then take the credentials from your service key and feed them to your app in the way that works best for you.

Ex:

```
cf create-service-key service-instance key-name
cf service-key service-instance key-name
```

The first command creates the service key, the second will display its credentials.